# Числа в виде массива

Tags: c

Есть идеи и возможно ли это? Как можно сравнить два числа, представленных в виде массива? Например: мне нужно создать условие "пока первое число больше второго", и вот загвоздка: числа-то представлены в виде массивов.

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, понятнее, представление чисел. Это просто поциферное представление?

Comment: Полагаю то что вы ищете называется "Длинная арифметика".

Comment: Если добавить тег [tag:c++], то можно использовать `lexicographical_compare`.

Comment: @АлексейЛобанов да,просто длинные числа,каждая цифра записывается в каждый i-й элемент массива

Comment: @Женя, вариант [tag:c++] не устраивает?

Comment: @alexolut то что вверху,не очень,честно говоря

Comment: @Женя, по какой причине? Нельзя использовать готовое решение, а нужно написать своё? Или требуется исключительно решение на [tag:c]?

Comment: @alexolut я бы сказал и то и другое,заставляют иногда самые банальные вещи расписывать,чтобы принцип понимать+пока чистый си

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В беззнаковом случае - просто начинайте сравнение со *старших* элементов массива. Например, считая `unsigned long` массивом из четырех `unsigned char`, можно написать

```
int cmp(unsigned char * a, unsigned char * b)
{
    for(int i = 3; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (a[i] < b[i]) return -1;
        if (a[i] > b[i]) return  1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int trivial(unsigned long a, unsigned long b)
{
    return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
}

void main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        unsigned long a = (rand() << 16) + rand();
        unsigned long b = (rand() << 16) + rand();
        if (cmp((unsigned char *)&a,(unsigned char *)&b) != trivial(a,b))
        {
            printf("Error for %lu %lu\n",a,b);
        }
    }
}
```

В знаковом случае надо учитывать знак. Так как разные представления могут использовать разный способ работы со знаком, тут надо смотреть на конкретную реализацию...

Comment: а что делает функция trivial?

Comment: @Женя, сравнивает два числа и возвращает результат сравнения в виде (-1,0,1) - (меньше, равно, больше).